# For loop of javascript working for constant length like 4,5 or 6 but not working for carts.length

Tags: javascript, html, django, cart

I am following a tutorial, but this piece of javascript code is not working at all. I tried to debug it using alert but I found that the first alert i.e 'going'alert is working but second alert 'work' alert is not working. When Ia am replacing 'carts.length with an integer like 3,4 or 5 it is working correctly
This is the javascript code:

```
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.update-cart');
alert("going")
for (let i=0;i < carts.length ;i++){
alert("work")
console.log("looping");
}
```

Tjis is the html code related to this:

```
{% for i in product %}
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{i.product_name}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{i.desc}}</p>
                            <button data-product="pr{{i.id}}" data-actions="add" class="btn btn-primary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 and forloop.counter > 0 and not forloop.last %}
            </div>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I want to use localStorage in javascript. I am using Django as backend. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(carts.length)` before for loop and check the value?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get total numbers of products, then you may do something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < parseInt("{{product|length}}"); i++)
```